# How to sort and filter this array of hashes using underscore

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I want to use `underscore.js` in order to take the highest price for each `tokenId` in the array of hashes below. I would imagine this would require running through the array twice, but perhaps there is a more efficient way. What's the best way to utilize underscore to only grab one hash keyed by `tokenId` and to select the one with the highest price with the fewest number of iterations through the entire array set?

```
const data = [
    {
        "tokenId": 1,
        "price": 1.8
    },
    {
        "tokenId": 1,
        "price": 2.0 
    },
    {
        "tokenId": 1,
        "price": 1.9
    },    
    {
        "tokenId": 2,
        "price": 5.0 
    },
    {
        "tokenId": 2,
        "price": 1.0 
    },
    
    {
        "tokenId": 3,
        "price": 1.9
    }    
]

// final result should be
// sortedFiltered = [{tokenId: 1, price: 2.0}, {tokenId: 2, price: 5.0}, {tokenId: 3, price: 1.9}]
```

Comment: create a custom function, called `filter_map`, or use `reduce` function and pass a empty object, then modify it base on condition

Comment: are you determined to use underscore? being general, would have you make two runs through (I'd start with groupBy, then sort).  custom code, as @Nur suggests, can avoid a second run.

Comment: @danh doesn't have to be underscore, figured that would remove a lot of cookie-cutter code. I'm open to any implementation with as few iterations as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reduce can do it in one iteration. Use the accumulator to keep max price values indexed by tokenId.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "tokenId": 1,
        "price": 1.8
    },
    {
        "tokenId": 1,
        "price": 2.0 
    },
    {
        "tokenId": 1,
        "price": 1.9
    },    
    {
        "tokenId": 2,
        "price": 5.0 
    },
    {
        "tokenId": 2,
        "price": 1.0 
    },
    
    {
        "tokenId": 3,
        "price": 1.9
    }    
]

// one iteration, with a custom function
const maxes = data.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (acc[o.tokenId] === undefined) acc[o.tokenId] = 0;
  if (acc[o.tokenId] < o.price) acc[o.tokenId] = o.price;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(maxes);
```

Comment: Going to study this, thanks dan.

Comment: Glad to help. @randombits. Please notice I changed the first condition from a "falsey" check to explicitly test for the missing key, because defualting the min value of zero there is also falsey. Note also, to handle negative values (probably not prices), you'd default to negative max int: `-Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`